# cURL (pycurl) FTP over HTTP proxy

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I writing simple uploading script and just catched next thing: curl tries to do **PUT** on a **ftp** server:

The simplified code:

```
import pycurl
from os.path import getsize

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'ftp://<ftp_name>:21/asus.c')
c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, 'username:password')
c.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, '10.0.0.35')
c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, 3128)
c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
f = open('asus.c')
c.setopt(pycurl.INFILE, f)
c.setopt(pycurl.INFILESIZE, getsize('asus.c'))
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.UPLOAD, 1)
c.perform()
```

Almost same code worked well few month ago, but:

```
* About to connect() to proxy <IP> port 3128 (#0)
*   Trying <IP>... * connected
* Connected to <IP> (<IP>) port 3128 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to <ftp_name>:21
* Server auth using Basic with user 'username'
> CONNECT <ftp_name>:21 HTTP/1.1
Host: <ftp_name>:21
User-Agent: PycURL/7.21.6
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
< 
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* Server auth using Basic with user 'username'
> PUT /asus.c HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic _______________________________
User-Agent: PycURL/7.21.6
Host: <ftp_name>:21
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 2627
Expect: 100-continue

220 ProFTPD 1.3.3 Server (______ FTP Server) [<IP>]
500 PUT not understood
500 AUTHORIZATION: not understood
500 USER-AGENT: not understood
500 HOST: not understood
500 ACCEPT: not understood
500 CONTENT-LENGTH: not understood
500 EXPECT: not understood
500 Invalid command: try being more creative
```

And same response when I try to do this from shell:

```
curl --upload-file "asus.c" --proxy 10.0.0.35:3128 \
--proxytunnel -u username:password ftp://<ftp_name>/asus.c
```

Why? What I missed?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to talk HTTP to an FTP server. Does your proxy work as an FTP proxy with these settings, e.g. from a browser or a known FTP client?

Comment: Yes. FileZilla connects (and uploads) fine through this proxy (it's a configured squid).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the format working for me.

```
curl --user 'ftp_user:ftp_password' --disable-epsv --proxytunnel -x 'yourproxy.com:port' -T 'your.localfile' 'ftp://remote.ftp.org:port/path' -v
```

I spent a lot of time to struggle with those parameters, let me know if you have curl as ftp problem.

Here is some parameter related:

`-U or --proxy-user <proxy_user:proxy_password>` if you need proxy credential

`-u or --user <ftp_user:ftp_password>` if you have remote ftp username and password

`--proxy-digest` if your proxy use digest authentication

`--proxy-basic` if your proxy use basic authentication

`--proxy-anyauth` if you want to detech proxy authentication

`-l or --list-only` if you only want to list an FTP directory.

`--digest` remote ftp using digest authentication

`--basic` remote ftp using basic authentication

`-3 or --sslv3` (SSL) Forces curl to use SSL version 3 when connect with remote ssl server

`-p or --proxytunnel` if you have `-x or --proxy` this option will cause non-http protocols to attempt to tunnel through the proxy instead of merely using it to do http-like operations.

`-v or --verbose` if you need verbose

`--ftp-ssl`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for ftp upload is:

```
curl -u "Remote-FTP-Username@remote.ftp.server Proxy-Username:Remote-Pass"     --ftp-account Proxy-Password --upload-file local-file     ftp://my-ftp.proxy.server:21/remote/upload/path/
```

Comment: The goal was to upload through http-proxy.